# How to differentiate between the device entering a Doze maintenance window and coming out of Doze

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

I have a method which periodically runs to keep a network connection alive. During Doze mode, I would like to disable it from running periodically and run exactly once during a maintenance window. When the device comes out of Doze, I would like the method to be called periodically again. How can I accomplish this ?

I have registered a receiver that listens for the `PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED` broadcast and then calls `PowerManager.isDeviceIdleMode()`. However, this return false for both cases - during a maintenance window and when the device exits Doze mode. How can I differentiate between them ?

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem, although i think android must differentiate this by sending a different state in the receiver or provide a function to ask such a state, i did not found anything related.

remember, the ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED is fired again when going back to doze after a period of time of 9-10 minutes.

the solution will be:

CURRENT DEVICE STATUS ->   "IN DOZE IDLE"

when you receive ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED and isDeviceIdleMode() is false
your status is "out of doze suspicion"
-DO your mantenience window work AND setup an alarm for 15 minutes in the future.

on the next mode change.

if the ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED is fired before the alarm and isDeviceIdleMode() is true, so, it was a mantenience window.
"out of doze false", 
( turn off the alarm ).

if the alarm is fired first, this means it was a "out of doze true confirmed"
-Do your setup for "out of doze" in the alarm

The timings of doze are in docs. be sure to check that first. ( may change in the future, as already has happened * may be there is a constant to get that value --i don't know ).

i consider this as a hack rather than a full fedged solution. but it works until any future expanded work on android provide another call to ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED, with "out of doze" status.